# Selenium-Webdriver in Ruby with minitest. Rake only runs one file with Dir.glob

Tags: ruby, selenium, rake, minitest

I can't seem to make Rake run all my test suites with Minitest, it only runs file **file_b.rb**, and can't figure it out why.

I have two files in that path, **file_a.rb** and **file_b.rb**, both have 4 test cases each.

First I tried:

```
task :default => :test
task :test do
  Dir.glob('./path/to/file_*.rb').each { |file| require file}
end
```

and the output:

```
$ N=4 rake
Run options: --seed 22083

# Running:

....

Finished in 30.830958s, 0.1297 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

4 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

And the same for

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "spec/2.3/web_v5_pc_qubit_*.rb"
end
```

Output:

```
$N=4 rake test
Run options: --seed 36188

# Running:

....

Finished in 18.307436s, 0.2185 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

4 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The main problem was the Rakefile and files in the directory to not having the correct path and filename convention used with Minitest.

This Rakefile solved the issue:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:all) do |t|
  t.libs << "tests"
  t.test_files = FileList['tests/test_*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end

Rake::TestTask.new(:webpc) do |t|
  t.libs << "tests"
  t.test_files = FileList['tests/test_web_*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end

task default: :all
```